# How can I set google recaptcha on laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5.4, recaptcha

I follow reference here :

https://github.com/anhskohbo/no-captcha

http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-google-recaptcha-code-and-validation-example-using-anhskohbo-no-captcha-packageexample.html

I have been installing it well

I follow all the steps

When I check the captcha, then I klik submit, the result like this :

[image]

Whereas I had check it

But, why there exist validation message?

My view blade like this :

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('g-recaptcha-response') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Captcha</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            {!! app('captcha')->display() !!}

            @if ($errors->has('g-recaptcha-response'))
                <span class="help-block">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('g-recaptcha-response') }}</strong>
                </span>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
```

My validation like this :

```
'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha'
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Well, clearly $error is not empty and contains data for the g-recaptcha-response. The given code does not provide enough information. Please add the relevant controller and routes you are using.